# Create Person Account Journey with Synchronized Data Sources

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, person-accounts, data-synchronization

The client would like to segment Person Accounts, and trigger a Journey based on a checkbox on the contact record. I'm synching the Contact and Account objects with all required fields, and had a developer help me write the SQL Query to create a Data Extension populated by only Person Accounts.

What would be the best way to create a Journey that's triggered by a field value change in SF?

I thought it would be good to have a DE with all Person Accounts, then another DE that's only Person Accounts with the 'test-journey' checkbox = true, but I'm not sure if this is just overcomplicating things. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the MC Connector, then you can just use the Salesforce Data Event for your entry. This would allow you to specify your entry criteria (i.e. trigger journey entry based on an event in your Person Account object), and select data from that and related objects in SF to enter with the subscriber in SFMC. Just sync all the objects w/ the data that you need and you're good to go.